# Python converting hex string to hex little endian byte code

Tags: python, hex

I'm trying to do this

```
pack("<Q", 0x401a12)
```

It works as it is, but I need pack() to take string hex code

```
addr = "0x401a12" # some hex from dump
pack("<Q", addr)
```

Any help?

Comment: It is not _Indian_, it is _endian_ (as in the "end").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `int` to convert to the corresponding integer:

```
struct.pack('<Q', int('0x401a12', base=16))
```